# Result of a Mysql query as a List view in android trough JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json

I would like to show data from a mysql as a list view of offices (listed by name) and when I click on a list item I should get more info about that office. Now the list doesn't appear. I'm new in Android (I start two weeks ago) so I can't understand how to fix...can somebodyy help me please?

```
public class Office extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{


ListView officeList;
InputStream is = null;

String result = "";
String result1 [];


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//setContentView(R.layout.office);
officeList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.officeL);



//the year data to send
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","0"));


 //http post
 try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.protocolliweb.com/mysqlcon.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();

 }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
 }

 //convert response to string
 try{
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
         }
         is.close();
         result=sb.toString();

         JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                     result1[i] = json_data.getString("nome");

                  } 

             officeList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result1));  
             officeList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

 }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
 }
```

}

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    String bread = officeList.getContext().toString();
    Bundle basket = new Bundle();
    basket.putString("key", bread);
    Intent a = new Intent(Office.this,Details.class);
    a.putExtras(basket);
    startActivity(a);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a `ListActivity`...

```
//setContentView(R.layout.office);
officeList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.officeL);
```

You can't use `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.officeL)` if you have `setContentView(...)` commented out.

If you don't set a content view, `ListActivity` will use its own default `ListView` which you access using...

```
officeList = getListView();
```

If you want to use a custom layout then do something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

...and use `setContentView(<name_of_custom_xml_layout>)`.

Note the `id` of the `ListView` is `android:id="@android:id/list"` which is the `id` that `ListActivity` will search for and will be the `ListView` returned by `getListView()`.

See the docs for [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) to understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank you ! ok the List is fixxed ...but doesn't  work anyway...the problem seems to be the JSON  coversion...any tip about?

Comment: Use logging to see what `result` and the array elements of `result1` are. That's the only way I would do it.